# Porting standalone Opencv exe file to run on a linux embedded board

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, raspberry-pi2, odroid

I am making an image processing project with Raspberry Pi 2, ODROID and Core-i7 PC (Windows 7).
Since RPi2 and ODROID have very less memory i need to know if i can make OpenCV applications on my PC and then copy the executables to RPi2 & ODROID which run Raspbian and Ubuntu respectively.

If yes then how?

In my PC i would be using OpenCV 2.4.9, Visual Studio 2013 & Qt creator.

Comment: I remember you can write your code in Visual Studio, compile it for Raspberry pi and copy the file to your pi to work. But this may require third party dependencies. Take this as a reference:    http://visualgdb.com/tutorials/raspberry/

Comment: the magic word is "cross-compile" for Raspberry Pi 2 maybe you find tutorials on google.